# Signal Problems between 2015 Macbook Pro and Dell 4K P2415Q Monitor

Tags: display, sleep-wake, thunderbolt, displayport

I just bought a [P2415Q](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&sku=860-BBFF) Monitor and connected it to my 2015 Macbook Pro with the DisplayPort to thunderbolt cable that was included with the monitor. It seemed ok at first, but after the first time the computer went into sleep mode I noticed the monitor wouldn't wake up. The message on the monitor was:

> There is no signal coming from your device. Please activate your
>   device to wake it up. If there is no display, press the monitor button
>   now to select the correct input source on the On-Screen-Display menu.

There is some information about this message in the monitor's [User's Guide](http://static.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/104995.pdf), but nothing that helps.

Through a combination of just random experimentation (unplugging/plugging, turning off/on, etc) I was eventually able to get the monitor and laptop connected again, but the problem recurred the next time the computer went into sleep.

I've now also seen a bunch of posts online complaining about similar issues with this monitor or the 27 inch variation. Does anyone have any suggestions about resolving this? I was thinking about getting an HDMI to HDMI cable and seeing if that was an improvement over the DP-mDP connection.

Another thing I notice while experimenting with connections was that when I plugged the DP cable into the monitor's DP-OUT connector **it seemed to work just as well** as plugging it to the DP-IN slot (i.e. worked initially but failed to wake up from sleep). Is that normal that the OUT would also work as an input?

Comment: I'd definitely recommend trying the HDMI cable. You'll probably be better off with that for full 4K anyway

Comment: @MitchellD Thanks I will try the HDMI to see if it helps with the sleep-wake issue, but when the monitor does work now with the included cable it is displaying at 3840 x 2160 at 60Hz. That's only when I can get it to wake up though and recognize the signal.

Answer (score 1):

After changing nothing, the monitor has been working fine for over a week now. All I can think of is maybe the computer was rebooted and that somehow solved the signal issues. I don't think any updates were installed and I'm still using the same DP cable. Resolution is still 3840x2160 at 60hz.

Answer (score 0):

I use a 2014 Macbook Pro with two Dell P2415Q via Display Port and I run into this issue from time to time.
The only solution appears to be to hard reset the monitor (disconnect cables and hold power for 10 seconds).

Rebooting the Macbook has no effect in my experience.